# FileNotFound issue when run the spark job in cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm a newbie in Spark, now, I set up a Spark with Docker

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.4.1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
    volumes:
       - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
       - ./data:/opt/spark-data

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.4.1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
       - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
       - ./data:/opt/spark-data

  spark-worker-2:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.4.1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
       - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
       - ./data:/opt/spark-data
```

this is a test code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("Api-app") \
        .getOrCreate()
url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aakashjainiitg/dbb668c58839d68d7903f508bf55043c/raw/1feec07802b4f53aceac450fa1aee5a87d9276e0/cities_data_bank.csv"
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)
file = SparkFiles.get("cities_data_bank.csv")
file_path = "file://"+file
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(file_path)
df.show()
spark.stop()
```

It work well on my local, but doesn't on the cluster.
`spark-submit --master spark://9e4ebff1f71b:7077 /opt/spark-apps/test.py`

Everyone please help me. Did I missing something?

The code run well on local, but got the FileNotFound in the cluster

Comment: When on the cluster, are you allowed to import files from external urls? Also, check the file path on the cluster. Either print or debug the file_path to see where it is pointing.

Comment: Hi @FullArray, I saw the spark download this file, and stored it at: Fetching https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aakashjainiitg/dbb668c58839d68d7903f508bf55043c/raw/1feec07802b4f53aceac450fa1aee5a87d9276e0/cities_data_bank.csv to /tmp/spark-c311b5a6-3942-4892-980f-31e7a14f3eca/userFiles-5d73bf95-a797-46f8-b9de-f4ff6909e06e/fetchFileTemp9740794267353551293.tmp

Comment: Hi @FullArray, and this is error message:
org.apache.spark.SparkFileNotFoundException (File file:/tmp/spark-c311b5a6-3942-4892-980f-31e7a14f3eca/userFiles-5d73bf95-a797-46f8-b9de-f4ff6909e06e/cities_data_bank.csv does not exist

Comment: @Steven.St please see my answer. Upvote or mark it as the answer if you think it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the comments between you and I, the remote csv file does not finish downloading to your cluster local file system. Therefore, your spark functions are not able to find it and read it. Moreover, you have tmp files which indicate partial but incomplete download. You need to investigate what cluster process is cutting abruptly the remote csv file download process when you are on your cluster. It could be your cluster firewall, directory permissions, or the remote file url is dynamic instead of static.

Comment: I ran  successfully `spark-submit --master spark://9e4ebff1f71b:7077 /opt/spark-apps/test.py` on one of my worker. But it didn't in master.

Comment: @StevenSt congrats on the run. So. is that the new error?

Comment: Hi @FullArray
this is my scenarios:
I have the python file as above, I have 1 spark cluster, 1 master, 2 workers;

I copy the python file and run it:
1, on master:  Fail -- filenotfound
2, on worker-1: Success
3, on worker-2: Success
The worker and master is the same docker image with default settings